# how send text(sendkey) to ckeditor in selenium python scripting -chrome driver

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, ckeditor

I can't send a text to the text box of CKEditor while I scripting.it not shown in the seleniumIDE recording also.Help me to fix this issueASAP

Comment: I think CKEedior show on your page as iframe, so you need switch to frame and only then send a text

Comment: yes it is inside iframe .but hw to switch to i frame? In python? and how can  find the body tag??

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know how looks your html, I'll just show you functions which you would use.

```
browser.switch_to_frame("your frame id")
```

So now you already in CKEditor frame

```
 el = browser.find_element_by_id("ckedit_element_id")
```

Comment: thank you bro ..it works ..:) never forget this help