# Interacting with CKEditor in Selenium - Python

Tags: python, selenium, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm currently working on automating an email generator, through a site I use for work. At the moment, I'm primarily using selenium and I'm pretty stuck because I can't get selenium to interact with the ckeditor on the page. So far I've tried...

Switching to the iframe, as discussed in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42488892/how-send-textsendkey-to-ckeditor-in-selenium-python-scripting-chrome-driver):

```
Input_Frame = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
browser.switch_to_frame(Input_frame)
Input_Element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset']")
Input_Element.send_keys('Hello')
```

I've used several xpath variations as well...
I also tried by css selector:

```
Input_Frame = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[class='cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset']")
Input_Frame = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[title='Rich Text Editor, CKeditorEmail']")
```

as well as index:

```
browser.switch_to_frame(0)
browser.switch_to_frame(1)
```

in all of the above cases, selenium is unable to find the element/frame, so I'm unable to actually enter any text.

I eventually tried fiddling with [this tutorial](https://www.calebthorne.com/blog/python/2012/06/07/ckeditor-element-for-webdriver) however it's a bit over my head and I wasn't really able to get many results. I did find that entering CKEDITOR.instances['CKeditorEmail'].setData('Hello World!'); into Firefox's console produced a change in the dispalyed text.

If anyone can offer a direction to point me to or come up with a solution I would greatly appreciate it. The rest of the automation is more or less finished --this is one of my first big projects and I'm taken back by how long this single step has taken me.

Also, in case anyone wants to take a peak at the [site's html](https://imgur.com/55b4e94d-23b6-413e-b4cd-a8431abe1d32).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you update the question with the text based formatted _HTML_ of the intended frame?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me, If you need more info you can find documentation here.
https://yizeng.me/2014/01/31/test-wysiwyg-editors-using-selenium-webdriver/

```
frame = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'cke_wysiwyg_frame')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
body = self.driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body')
body.send_keys('tester')
```